# Dynamically resize JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, resize, window

I use this plug-in (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/).
I could easily set it up and configure some parameters.
The thing that I can't get to work is to resize this plug-in on a javascript triggered method.
In other words :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#myGallery').galleryView({
        panel_width: 850,
        panel_height: 350,
        autoplay : true,
        transition_interval: 2000,
        frame_height:0,
        show_filmstrip:false
    });
    });
</script>
```

The thing that I have to change is panel_width.
please help

Comment: Your code seems fine except may be it should be written outside of "$(function() {})".

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to do something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CaDsH/) ...